# Alternatives to signing Git commit hashes, now that SHA1 is broken?

Tags: git, sha1

SHA1 is [broken](https://shattered.io).  That means that signing Git commit hashes is also broken – it relies on SHA1 being collision-resistant, which it obviously isn't.

What are some alternatives?  Are there ways to take a Git repository and create a better hash out of it?  Is Git planning on switching hashes?

Comment: I think for git and many other tools this is more of a theoretical problem at this time than a practical one so I wouldn't start running for the hills just yet. The current attack relies on generating two files that has the same hash, not creating a file that has the same hash as some other existing file. *That* attack is still impractical for the time being. So to spoof a signature would still require more cpu time than it is worth. That is, unless you're creating top secret NSA type software in which case putting it on github is probably a bad idea anyway.

Comment: For more information you should read [what Linus Torvalds posted on the issue](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/7tp2gYWQugL). And yes, he says: "yes, git will eventually transition away from SHA1".

Comment: But no, right now there are no alternatives, other than to switch *from* git. But again, you shouldn't start running for the hills just yet.

Comment: In cryptography terms, to break Git commit signatures, you must defeat something called *second preimage resistance*, and the example with a broken SHA-1 hash is not that. Or in other words, what @LasseV.Karlsen said.

Comment: When a hash is broken, what you learn about is the _public_ vulnerabilities.  The fact that there are any collisions at all indicates that the hash should no longer be used, as private parties may find further ways to break this hash and not reveal them.  Similarly, further breaks may be found in the future and at that time any hashes made now will be breakable.  It's time now to rehash our repositories with a more secure hash, so that our code in the future cannot be spoofed.

Comment: When you're looking for ways to prove you are safe to yourself, you miss the creative ways the attackers are finding to make you unsafe.  It's not secure to think "this seeming danger is okay because ..."; it's secure to think "how could I take advantage of this seeming danger to make it even more dangerous?"  This is what those motivated to change your code will be thinking.  There is no loss of safety to make the git hash stronger, right now, and it can be done in a backwards-compatible way.  There is no reason to argue against this aside from nobody having the time and energy to do it.

Comment: @fuzzyTew You are correct, *but* I have no reason to believe that the second-preimage resistance of SHA-1 is broken.  An attacker would need to get a malicious version signed, and could then pass off their other malicious version as the official version.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools out there which take stronger hashes of file trees than git.  One example is [ipfs](https://ipfs.io/).